# Most efficient way to crop center of gradient

Tags: android, android-drawable

What is a most efficient way to generate gradient and crop center part of it like in this picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkfkE.jpg

```
int w = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
ShapeDrawable.ShaderFactory sf = new ShapeDrawable.ShaderFactory() {
            @Override
            public Shader resize(int width, int height) {
                RadialGradient gradient = new RadialGradient(w / 2.0F, 0, w / 2.0F, Color.WHITE, Color.BLUE, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
                return gradient;
            }
        };
PaintDrawable p = new PaintDrawable();
p.setShape(new RectShape());
p.setShaderFactory(sf);
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to show only part of generated gradient as a view background.

Comment: Use Shader.setLocalMatrix

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure I correctly explain what I want to achieve. I have a picture and a semi transparent gradient like in my question above. And I want to overlay center part of gradient over picture.

Comment: Still don't know what you want to do,  maybe some pic with image view and gradient?